# How can I delete a specific row and column pointing to a cell from a dataframe having a special character in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, the dataframe is:

```
data = [['@Why', 1, 2], ['Stack', 1 ,'Example'], ['Overflow', 2, 'Anything'], ['row&', 3, 'Group' ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

From here I want to delete the *@why* and *row&* rows, but I want to keep the rows and columns data the same, like it should not delete the entire row or column. It should only delete the cell value.

Comment: What is the error message? For what kind of operation? Can you add it to your question? (But ****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.)

Comment: lets take the df is :

data = [['@Why', 1, 2], ['Stack', 1 ,'Example'], ['Overflow', 2, 'Anything'], ['row&', 3, 'Group' ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

So the new df should look like :

data_output = [['', 1, 2], ['Stack', 1 ,'Example'], ['Overflow', 2, 'Anything'], ['', 3, 'Group' ]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_output, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

Think it in a way where we have a table but I just want to delete the value from a cell, for example 

Select * from Table limit 1 
         A.          B.       C
Comments | Are | Used |

I want to delete Comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '' if any(c in "!@#$%^&*()-+?_=,<>/" for c in x) else x)
df
```

Output:

```
        A       B   C
0               1   2
1   Stack       1   Example
2   Overflow    2   Anything
3               3   Group
```

Comment: Its almost what I was looking for, can you give me something where I can delete the cell from the entire df where ever the special character is present ?

Comment: Hi you can't delete cell in DF.

Comment: I meant replace with None or empty string

Comment: Please check the updated code